# Help identifying this device (Sunflower tablet pp3333) and required linux drivers

Tags: linux, devices, tablet, wacom

[image: sunflower tablet]

Hello, I received this device as pictured some years ago, but was never able to figure out what drivers to use for it. My computer does not have the AT connector or serial port, but I do have a serial-USB adapter, as well as an AT keyboard connector-ps/2 adapter. If I plug in the serial to USB adapter part, linux detects the *adapter* and creates an entry for `/dev/ttyUSB0`, but the LED on the device does not light up. If I plug in the ps/2 connector with a ps/2 purple (keyboard) to USB adapter, the LED lights up, but if the AT K/B-USB is not plugged in, no device entry is created. I tried doing `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` but that produces no output when clicking on the pen's buttons or scribbling with it on the pad.

So how do I get this device to work in linux? I would love to use it to do simple drawing in gimp for example. I figure it is a pad designed specifically to generate Chinese characters, not really for drawing, but that shouldn't make a difference (though maybe it helps as a clue for someone to figure this out).

Searching for "sunflower tablet" or other combinations yielded no success or even clues. And no, I don't read Chinese. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Using google translate, I found that the chinese text at the bottom is just declarations that it complys with chapter 15 of the us federal radio rules, or at least something along those lines. With a bit of quick googling, I also found that I believe you have a Super Pen PP3333 Uc-Logic graphics tablet. I didn't have enough time to see if I could find drivers but I hope this helps anyway.

Comment: The superpen clue might just be the clue I needed. I even had the 2001 driver source hidden in a directory on my machine somewhere! I will test that out and report back when I can, thank you!

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xf86superpen/

Comment: http://xf86superpen.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Glad I could help.